# DomDocument Get attribute in XML ns format

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, xml-namespaces, xls

Suppose you have an xml doc with tags with ns colons such as `<person:core age="25" />`, how do you get the attribute value using PHP DOMDocument?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing XML attributes within a namespace tag (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698870/parsing-xml-attributes-within-a-namespace-tag-php)

Comment: If the XML does not declare that prefix, it will be dropped and the duplicate is: [PHP DOMDocument getting Attribute of Tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597746/php-domdocument-getting-attribute-of-tag)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into the `DOMDocument::getElementsByTagNameNS()` ***[[docs]](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagnamens.php)*** method, which should do what you need. I can't provide you with specific code, since you haven't included the XML file you're working with.