# get element by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, selectors-api

How can I get the image url which embeded in below media: thumbnail tag ?

```
<link href="http://example.com" type="text/html">
<media:content>
<media:thumbnail url="http://example2.com/1.jpg" width="150" height="100"></media:thumbnail>
</media:content>
</link>
```

I am looking for something like

```
var link = tag.querySelectorAll('link')[0];
var media = link.querySelector('media:content');
var thumbnail= link.querySelector('media:thumbnail');
var url= thumbnail.getAttribute('url');
```

but obviousely querySelector could not retrieve the value of media:content

Comment: Have a look at these posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121933/parsing-xml-using-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597746/php-domdocument-getting-attribute-of-tag

Comment: The cited duplicates are PHP oriented, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply to use `attr`

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Pnb9z/)

Comment: Thanks, it is good when you access to jquery library I am using javascript and I did manage to get it by below code   

     var mediaThumbnail = link.getElementsByTagName('thumbnail')[0];
     var imageUrl = mediaThumbnail.getAttribute('url');

Answer (score 0):

```
$('media:thumbnail').attr('url');
```

This may help you